# what is the formula for converting negative epoch time?

Tags: c#, unix-timestamp

I have problem with negative epoch time. I have a third party program that generate me the epoch time. I am using that program to generate epoch time for me where I am keeping the date and time the same for all while only changing the year to get the epoch times below for testing. My date and time should be 01/01/yyyy 12:00:00 AM for all yyyy.

This is what I have:

```
 var epoch = new DateTime(1904, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var ofset = 6*60*60; // 6hr different

        Console.WriteLine("1900: " + epoch.AddSeconds(-126122400 - ofset)); // 1900
        Console.WriteLine("1904: " + epoch.AddSeconds(21600 - ofset)); // 1904
        Console.WriteLine("1905: " + epoch.AddSeconds(31644000 - ofset)); // 1905
        Console.WriteLine("1970: " + epoch.AddSeconds(2082866400 - ofset)); // 1970
        Console.WriteLine("1971: " + epoch.AddSeconds(2114402400 - ofset)); // 1971
        Console.WriteLine("1972: " + epoch.AddSeconds(2145938400 - ofset)); // 1972
        Console.WriteLine("1973: " + epoch.AddSeconds(-2117406496 - ofset)); // 1973
        Console.WriteLine("1974: " + epoch.AddSeconds(-2085870496 - ofset)); // 1974
        Console.WriteLine("2016: " + epoch.AddSeconds(-760494496 - ofset)); // 2016
```

The output is:

```
1900: 1/1/1900 12:00:00 AM
1904: 1/1/1904 12:00:00 AM
1905: 1/1/1905 12:00:00 AM
1970: 1/1/1970 12:00:00 AM
1971: 1/1/1971 12:00:00 AM
1972: 1/1/1972 12:00:00 AM
1973: 11/24/1836 5:31:44 PM
1974: 11/24/1837 5:31:44 PM
2016: 11/24/1879 5:31:44 PM
```

As you can see, starting from line 1973 (where the epoch time is negative) the date and year and time out put are all wrong. What should I do to get the correct date, year and time?

UPDATE:

For raw data with date set at 10:11:45.654 AM 5/26/2016 then this is what I see in the database:

```
<Timestamp>
            <Name>Date Created</Name>
            <Cluster>
                <Name></Name>
                <NumElts>4</NumElts>
                <I32>
                    <Name></Name>
                    <Val>0</Val>
                </I32>
                <I32>
                    <Name></Name>
                    <Val>-1482223616</Val>
                </I32>
                <I32>
                    <Name></Name>
                    <Val>-747850591</Val>
                </I32>
                <I32>
                    <Name></Name>
                    <Val>0</Val>
                </I32>
            </Cluster>
        </Timestamp>
```

Comment: Why would you expect adding negative seconds to a date in 1904 would result in a date in 1973?

Comment: If the epoch is 1904/01/01, and a negative number gives you 1900/01/01, then one would expect a smaller number (i.e. negative number with larger absolute value) to give you a date *before* the epoch. I think there's something screwy in your data.

Comment: Why is epoch set to 1/1/1904?  Epoch is 1/1/1970.

Comment: the epoch is generated by labview. please see here http://www.ni.com/tutorial/7900/en/

Comment: does anyone have any suggestion? looking at this link i see that it is common for mac http://www.silisoftware.com/tools/date.php?inputdate=-529442816&inputformat=unix

Comment: My suggestion is that the number you have for 1973 is incorrect. It's not possible for 2145938400 to be the value for 1972 and -2117406496 to be the number for 1973. Not if the value is supposed to be the number of seconds since 1904/01/01. To get the correct date and time, you need to get the correct timestamp. Also, this has nothing to do with Unix timestamps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I discovered the problem: integer overflow. I don't know *where* it's happening, but that's the problem.

Consider, the number of seconds from 1904/01/01 until 1973/01/01 is 2,177,539,200. The maximum value for an integer is 2,147,483,648. So the offset value for 1973 is larger than will fit in an integer.

If you take the number 2,177,539,200 and cast it as an `int`, the value you get is -2,117,428,096. And if you plug that number into your date calculation, you get 1836/11/24 17:31:44. Here's the test code:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var epoch = new DateTime(1904, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    var offset = TimeSpan.FromHours(6);

    // How many seconds between 1904/01/01 and 1973/01/01?
    var timestamp1973 = (new DateTime(1973, 01, 01, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local) - epoch).TotalSeconds;
    Console.WriteLine("1973 timestamp = {0:N0}", timestamp1973);
    Console.WriteLine("Verify calculation: {0}", epoch.AddSeconds(timestamp1973));

    // How many seconds is that different from int.MaxValue?
    var overflow = timestamp1973 - int.MaxValue;
    Console.WriteLine("Overflow = {0:N0}", overflow);

    // So take int.MaxValue and add the overflow
    var wrongTimeStamp = int.MaxValue;
    wrongTimeStamp += (int) overflow;
    Console.WriteLine("wrong time stamp = {0:N0}", wrongTimeStamp);

    // And the calculation with that value is:
    Console.WriteLine("Wrong date = {0}", epoch.AddSeconds(wrongTimeStamp));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And the output:

```
1973 timestamp = 2,177,539,200
Verify calculation: 1973-01-01 00:00:00
Overflow = 30,055,553
wrong time stamp = -2,117,428,096
Wrong date = 1836-11-24 17:31:44
```

So, either the third party program is incorrectly sending you a signed 32-bit integer in the data, or something in your program is incorrectly casting the signed 64-bit number that LabView creates to a signed 32-bit number. *Somewhere* somebody's converting 64 bits to 32 bits, and things go sideways.

### After comments

If the data is indeed a signed integer, then it looks like your only option is to treat it as unsigned. That will prevent you from showing dates prior to 1904, but it will give you range up to February 2040. To do that:

```
int signedValue = ReadFromDatabase();
uint unsignedValue = (uint)signedValue;
var theDate = epoch.AddSeconds(unsignedValue);
```

Comment: hi Jim. It is overflow to me, too. But, I am using a third party program and assign the date. The date is then inserted in to database by the third party program. I am basically copy and paste the date shown in the database. Also, I checked that the thirdparty program can retrieve the date and display correctly.

Comment: @user1801381: Then the third party program knows something about the data that you don't. Is it possible that the field in the database is a 64-bit number? The other program could be treating the value as unsigned, which would work for positive dates, but you wouldn't be able to represent anything prior to 1904. If the other program can read and display the data, that leads me to believe that your program is misinterpreting things, most likely in obtaining the value from the database.

Comment: Hi Jim. I literally perform copy and paste manually without using any code so it is not a casting issue. The field in the database is a of type string nvarchar(max). Please see my updated question for the value I got from the raw data.

Comment: @user1801381: It looks to me like the only thing you can do is treat it as unsigned. That will prevent you from displaying any date prior to 1904. And the maximum date you'll be able to represent is 02/06/2040 06:28:15. One second after that, the unsigned integer rolls over and you'll be back to 1904.

Comment: @user1801381: I added an example for converting to unsigned.

Comment: Thanks Jim. That fixed it.